# Which of the following are topology?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.Let
$$ S = \{ U\subseteq \mathbb R : U \ \ is \ \ either\ \ bounded \ \ open \ \ or \ \ empty \ \ or \ \ \mathbb R \}$$

and

$$ T = \{ U\subseteq \mathbb R : U \ \ is \ \ either\ \ unbounded \ \ open \ \ or \ \ empty \ \ or \ \ \mathbb R \}$$

Then, on $\mathbb R$

1. S is topology but not T.
2. T is a topology but not S.
3. both S and T are topologies.
4. neither S nor T is a topology.

My attempt is :

G = $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (1,n)$ which is not open in S, so S is not topology, because arbitrary union of open set is not open .

G' = $(-\infty,1)\cap (0,\infty) = (0,1)$ which is not open in T, So T is not a topology.

I would be thankful who someone give me your valuable time to check my solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your solutions are correct.  (Although you should observe that $G$ and $G'$ are also not empty nor all of the reals.)

You have constructed an (arbitrary) union of bounded open sets, $G$, that is not itself a bounded open set, the empty set, or $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus you have shown that $S$ is not a topology.

You have constructed a finite intersection of unbounded open sets, $G'$ that is not itself an unbounded open set, the empty set, or $\mathbb{R}$.  Thus you have shown that $T$ is not a topology.

Answer (score 0):

Unions of open sets are always open. But S is not topology because it is not bounded and also T is not. The reason union is open is as follows.Since open ball around every point exists for each set so it exists in the union also. The problem occurs with intersection where it infinite intersection of open sets need not be open

Comment: I have a counter example of union of open set is not open because it is not bounded

Comment: @user120386 an open set need not be bounded the set of reals is unbounded and is open

Comment: Definitely it is open in usual topology on $\mathbb R$ but not in S

Comment: @yes you are right i have edited my answer but i was trying to point out that the set you got was open but not bounded hence not in topology.